# Changing CSS Attribute on click in React while using Styled Components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm making a web in HTML, CSS, and plain JS. I'm planning to convert this into ReactJS. Although, I'm planning to make this into a single JSX file to export it to App.js. My friend recommended me to use Styled Components so I can make all of it into a single JSX file.

The problem is, I have a button which shows a Modal Box when clicked, using the function in plain JS. Currently, I'm having trouble implementing the function on ReactJS.

My code in React looks a bit like this:

```
//The Exported page
import React, {useState} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export function InfoCalon(){

  return(
    <CustomStyle>
    <div class="content-container">
        <button id="button1" class="button" >Button 1</button>
    </div>

    <div id="modal" class="modalpopup">
        <div class="modal-content">
            //Modal Contents
        </div>
    </div>
    </CustomStyle>
  )
}

const CustomStyle = styled.div`
background-color: black;
color: white;

.button {
  border: none;
  min-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-flexbox;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px 10% 10px 10%;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.button:hover{
  transform: scale(1.02);
}

.button:active{
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition-duration: 0.05s;
}

.modalpopup {
  display: none;          //The attribute that I want to change on button1 click to display: block.
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #102037;
  margin: 7% auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1% 3% 3% 3%;
  width: 80%;
}
`
```

I tried using onClick in the button and made a function to show the modal, but I always failed, getting errors such as "var is null()".

Before converting to ReactJS, the code in the JS file was:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("button1");

btn1.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

For the HTML and CSS code, it's pretty much everything that's in CustomStyle.

I would appreciate any response for this, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the InfoCalon component, you can maintain an internal state which defines whether the modal is open or not

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

Now to toggle this you need to attach an event listener to the button like this

```
<button id="button1" onClick={(e) => setIsOpen(!isIsOpen)} class="button" >Button 1</button>
```

Now all you need to do is conditionally render the modal i.e. only show the modal if the isOpen is true.

```
{isOpen && (<div id="modal" class="modalpopup">
    <div class="modal-content">
        //Modal Contents
    </div>
</div>)}
```

And you also need to remove the **display: none** from the styles of the modal.

Answer (score 2):

`styled-component` are React components, so you can pass props to them. I would suggest adding a `isClicked` (*or similar*) state to the `InfoCalon` component and update it from a click handler attached to the button. Pass the `isClicked` value as a prop to `CustomStyle` component.

```
export function InfoCalon() {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(false);

  const clickHandler = () => setIsClicked(clicked => !clicked);

  return(
    <CustomStyle isClicked={isClicked}>
      <div class="content-container">
        <button id="button1" class="button" onClick={clickHandler}>
          Button 1
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="modal" class="modalpopup">
        <div class="modal-content">
          //Modal Contents
        </div>
      </div>
    </CustomStyle>
  )
}
```

Use a props function to access the `isClicked` prop and set the display rule accordingly.

```
const CustomStyle = styled.div`
  ...

  .modalpopup {
    display: ${({ isClicked }) => isClicked ? "block" : "none"};
    ...
  }

  ...
`;
```

An improved design might be to break all the CSS up into several individual style-components, where each can take their own props. You could for example, make the modal div its own component and pass an `isOpen` prop directly to it to set the style.

Example

```
const Modal = styled.div`
  display: ${({ isOpen }) => isOpen ? "block" : "none"};          
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
`;

const ModalContent = styled.div`
  background-color: #102037;
  margin: 7% auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1% 3% 3% 3%;
  width: 80%;
`;

export function InfoCalon() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => setIsOpen(open => !open);

  return(
    <CustomStyle isClicked={isClicked}>
      <div class="content-container">
        <button id="button1" class="button" onClick={toggleModal}>
          Button 1
        </button>
      </div>

      <Modal id="modal">
        <ModalContent>
          // Modal Contents
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </CustomStyle>
  )
}
```

Comment: If I were to make another button which opens another modal, does that mean I have to make another copy of toggleModal with a different name?

Comment: @GigaHidjrikaAA Yes, if you want them to function independently.